# How to change user permissions on a folder so postgres can acces it?

Tags: windows, postgresql

I want to export some data of my PostgreSQL Database with the COPY command.

The manual states: "COPY with a file name instructs the PostgreSQL server to directly read from or write to a file. The file must be accessible by the PostgreSQL user (the user ID the server runs as) and the name must be specified from the viewpoint of the server."

How can I make sure that the requirements are fullfilled, or otherwise enable them?

Im using Postgres 10 on a Windows 7 Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Login as PostgreSQL operating system user and try to read the file.

Alternatively, try `COPY` and see if you get an error message.

Comment: Using Copy, i get a error message: Permission denied. 

How do i log in as PostgreSQL OS user?

Comment: Enter the user name and password after you turn on the computer? But if `COPY` says so, you are lacking permissions. Make sure the PostgreSQL operating system user has read access to the file and all the direcrories that contain it.

Comment: Sorry, i'm a total beginner when it comes to those things. 
I know PostgrSQL lacks the permission, to write files on my disk, but i don't know, how to change this. 
Also, Windows doesn't know the user PostgreSQL, so I can't grant him acces to my files.

Comment: The PostgreSQL user is typically called `postgres`. It is ok that you know little about PostgreSQL and Windows, but it is not possible to teach you Windows system administration basics in a Stackoverflow answer. Maybe you should attend a course or get a system administrator to show you the ropes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually a permissions problem at all - what you need to do is change your backslashes in the path to forward slashes.  So when pulling in some data I found it worked just so (no quotes):

```
\i C:/folder/stuff/load_database.sql
```

Although this wasn't a COPY, I'd imagine the file path problem is pretty universal, and the solution would work just as well with copy, ie:

```
COPY "sometable" TO 'C:/folder/morestuff/info.csv'  DELIMITER ',' HEADER;
```

Source for this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29767/permission-denied-in-file-trying-to-import